# Spark Dataframe : Accessing next record in map function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DF with a timestamp column, sort by this column. Is there any way to do this : for each record, acces the next record to calculate time diffrence between the two lines? I don't think this is possible in a map function, since the two lines may be processed on different nodes.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you use a HiveContext? If so, you could use Window Functions (assuming you have spark 1.4+)

Comment: thx for reply. I have Spark 1.5, but I never used Window functions. I'll see what it does.

Comment: I added a response with an example. If it helps, please mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Spark 1.4 or later, if you can use a Hive Context, the follwing code may work for you:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.LongType
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
val df = hc.read.format("...").load("...")

val timestamp_column = df("timestamp_column")
val next_row_timestamp = lead(timestamp_column, 1).over(Window.orderBy(timestamp_column))

val newDF = df.withColumn("time_difference", next_row_timestamp.cast(LongType) - timestamp_column.cast(LongType))
```

**Explanation:**

In this code, I am using the `lead(e: Column, offset: Int)` window function available in the `functions` package ([doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$)). This function actually creates a new column with the data in the column `e` (`timestamp_column` in the example) shiffted by `offset` (`1` in th example). To work properly, it must be followed by a `over(window: WindowSpec)` call, which defines a window using the Window object. This window may be composed by a partition and an order. In this case, I set just the order using `Window.orderBy`.

Finally, I add a column with the difference in seconds (or milliseconds? not sure) between both columns to the original DataFrame using `withColumn`.

For more details, the following link explains the idea very well, with examples:
https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html

---

**Edit:**

As pointed out in the comments, the solution above can be very inefficient. As an alternative, it's possible to use an RDD solution:

```
val newRDD = df.rdd.zipWithIndex.flatMap {
  case (row, idx) => (0 to 1).map { lag => (idx - lag, row) }
}
.groupByKey
.values
.map { pair =>
  val pairArray = pair.toArray
  val timeDiff = {
    if (pairArray.length == 1) null
    else pairArray(1).getAs[java.sql.Timestamp]("timestamp_column").getTime - pairArray(0).getAs[java.sql.Timestamp]("timestamp_column").getTime
  }
  Row.merge(Row(timeDiff), pairArray(0))
}

val newSchema = StructType(StructField("time_diff", LongType, true) +: df.schema.fields)
val newDf = df.sqlContext.createDataFrame(newRDD, newSchema)
```

The resulting data frame in `newDF` will have a new column "time_diff" containing the time difference in milliseconds between current row and the next one.

Comment: This is extremely inefficient and practically useless in practice.

Comment: @zero323 so what would be the alternative? At the moment I can only think of `df.rdd.zipWithIndex.map` followed by a join or a group by

Comment: This is one option. Another one is sliding from MLlib. Problem with window functions is that without `PARTITION BY` this pretty much equivalent to `repartition(1)`.

Comment: *next record* makes sense only when ordering is specified. Solution with groupByKey just returns difference between randomly combined rows.